# Interesting property of sum of powers of integers from 1 to 114.

Tags: sequences-and-series

When I have this list of specific X values:

$X: 1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, 112, 113, 114.$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{114}n = 6555$$

$$6555/19 = 345$$

The sum of these $X$ values divided by $19$ is an integer.

---

Then I square each $X$ value:

$X^2: 1, 4, 9, 16, \ldots, 12544, 12769, 12996.$

The sum of these $X^2$ values divided by $19$ is also an integer.

---

Then I cube each $X$ value, and the pattern continues.

Is there any reason for this property mathematically? Or does it just exist?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why divide by $19$? Why up to $114$. How did you come across this?

Comment: $19 \mid n = 114$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$, $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, etc

Comment: 114 is exactly the total number of sourates in Coran.

Comment: The pattern continues up through $\sum n^{17},$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{114}n^{18}$ is not divisible by $19.$

Comment: @DavidK  Nor for other multiples of 18.   (36, 54, 76, 108, ...)

Comment: @user15994 Yes, of course not for other multiples of $18$ (for the same reason), but now I understand the comment you posted under one of the answers!

Comment: The current title is too broad. I suggest something like: "Why does adding integer powers until 114 give a multiple of 19?"

Comment: @user15994 The $k$ where the formula for $\sum n^k$ entails dividing by 19 aren't the multiples of 18, but $19a-1$, e.g. 37.

Answer (score 10):

Hint : $$\sum_{j=1}^k j =\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ $$\sum_{j=1}^k j^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. What is this rule known as and when did people discover it?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html

Answer (score 6):

This is because $19|114$.

$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac {n(n+1)}{2}$

And $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac {n(n+1)(2k + 1)}6$.

And as $19$ is a prime number that divides $114$, $19$ will divide both $\frac {19*20}{10}$ and $\frac {19*20*39}6$.

In general if $n = 19*m$ then

$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac {n(n+1)}2 = \frac {19m(19m + 1)}2 = 19\frac {m(19m+1)}2$ and since either $m$ is even or $19m + 1$ is even, $2|m(19m+1)$.

Likewise $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 =\frac {19m(19m + 1)(38m + 1)}6 = 19 \frac {m(19m + 1)(38m + 1)}6$.  Again either $m$ or $19m + 1$ is even so $2|m(19m+1)(38m + 1)$.  And if $m$ has remainder $0$ when divided by $3$ then $3|m$. If $m$ has remainder $1$ when divided by $3$ then $3|38m + 1$.  And if $m$ has remainder $2$ when divided by $3$ then $3|19m+1$  So $3|m(19m+1)(38m + 1)$.  So $6|m(19m+1)(38m+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

We can prove that 
$a^{n}+b^{n}=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^{2}-...+a^{2}b^{n-3}-ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$ by simplifying the right hand side to the left hand side. However, this is only true for odd integers $n$, also note that the property no longer holds if $18|n$.

In the set $1;2;3;4;5;\cdots;113;114$:

- The number $114$ is divisible by $19$, so all the sums $1+113;2+112;3+111;4+110;\cdots;56+58$ and number $57$ are divisible by $19$
- Apply the equality above, we will have $1^n+113^n;2^n+112^n;3^n+111^n;4^n+110^n;\cdots;56^n+58^n$ and $57^n$ and $114^n$ are divisible by $19$ too $\Rightarrow 1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\cdots+114^n$ is divisible by $19$ for all odd integers $n.$

Comment: There are flaws in this proof before I edited, luckily I know it before anyone notice (see [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2751979/revisions))

Comment: For n=18, 36, 54, 76, 90, 108, ... ?

Comment: We _did_ notice, but you fixed it faster than we could type the objections.

Comment: This proof is good for odd powers, but $19\not\mid 1^2 + 113^2.$

Comment: And in fact there cannot be a general proof for all even powers, because the claim is not true for $18$th powers.

Comment: And now I see that's what the comment by @user15994 is about: $n$ is the exponent, and if it is a multiple of $18$ the claim fails.

Comment: Your first formula is valid only for odd $n$. For even $n$, the sign of $b^n$ is wrong. For example, $a^2+b^2 \neq (a+b)(a-b)$ .